# How do I solve a lot of Failure Audit (529 680) which are appearing in event viewer “Security” tab?

Tags: authentication, webserver, attack-prevention

was trying to consume an Web Services that I have published on the Web but I couldn't thing is that when I got into the server and check the "Event Viewer" I have a LOT of "Failure Audit" and they keep coming as we speak.

So I guess someone is trying to hack in my server. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely noone is trying to hack your server. At least not based on the information provided.

There isn't any harm - actually any problem whatsoever - in getting audit failure events on a public facing web facing server. IIS provides a number of authentication mechanisms.

These failures occur when one method is tried (and fails). The next method in the list takes over and it works as it should.

One of my web servers only takes domain authenticated requests. IE always tries unauthenticated first, so I get hundreds of thousands of these events (albeit with different ID numbers since I'm on 2008 R2) a day.

On a related note you should really look at upgrading. Server 2003 is end of life in June 2015 and 2000 is long since dead. Really had to think about what ID numbers you were referring to.